# I've set up a button style with CSS/HTML, how can I make the button click redirect to another page?

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.button {
            background-color: #fdf7b8;
            border: none;
            color:black;
            padding: 15px 50px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Palatino, serif;
            display:inline-block;
            font-size: 32px;
            margin: 6px 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 2px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;

}


.button1:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button button1">Our Vision</button><br>
<button class="button button1">Downloads</button><br>
<button class="button button1">About Us</button><br>
```

Would I be able to keep the style and have the buttons send to a URL onclick? Is there a way to only do it with HTML/CSS and not use JavaScript?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: @StephenC Thank you Stephen, should I just remove this post?